# iphone app migrate to ipad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

i just read the app guideline something. 
"iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution. "

but my game can run on iphone 3g,3gs,4g. it can also run on ipad, but the coordinate is different and i don't provide a larger sprite image.

will it be rejected? i don't think i have time to change my code before summer holiday.

Comment: what does `the coordinate is different` mean?

Comment: Some sprouts appear in the correct position since I use winSize, others appear at 1/4 of the screen since I use 480by 320 directly. So it is a mess

Answer (score 1):

Would you say it runs ok on the iPad? Is it playable? If so I think you'll be fine, but you know it's all up to Apple. I haven't seen your game running on an iPad so it's really hard to give you a reliable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If an app runs on a 3GS, and doesn't have any iPad specific xib's in the app's info plist. or check the UI paradigm at runtime, it will run inside a 320 x 480 window on the iPad in iPhone compatibility mode without any changes.  It will also run in a pixel doubled window on the iPad, again without the app knowing a thing about that.

It's sort of like running in an emulator sandbox.

Comment: I use 480 by 320 for some cases but winSize for other cases. So some stuffs cover only 1/4 of iPad but the others cover the whole screen